# How can I create a new process in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, fork

How I can create a new process in the Linux kernel?

Because the function fork could not be implemented in the kernel... Then as How I can create a new process in the Kernel?

Thx.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c

Comment: Can you please rephrase this? "could not implementen" makes no sense in English and I can't decipher what you're trying to say, sorry.

Comment: Don't create processes inside the kernel

Answer (score 2):

In-kernel process can be created using [kthread_create](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kthread.h#L13) (or `kthread_run`, which is similar to `kthread_create`, but also starts the thread).

User-space program can be called using [call_usermodehelper](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/kmod.c#L616).

Creating generic user-space process in the kernel is discouraged (and actually unclear).